# Why is my SQL query execution slow

Tags: javascript, sql

My Software is JavaScript based. The code runs a query in an Oracle database and contacts the result as a string.
When `gridData`'s size is bigger than 10 and some of the results return null, the execution time is slow.

Is this a code or query related problem ?

```
var related_approver="";
var tSql;
var tResult;
var extra_approver="";
gridData = Grid_RelateUnitObj.getData();
    if (gridData.length > 0){               
    for (i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++){
         tSql= "select users.id||'_'||users.username||';' from                                                         organizationunit,users where organizationunit.manageroid=users.oid and validtype=1 and"+" organizationunit.id='"+gridData[i][0]+"'";
            tResult=tDbConn.query(tSql);    
        if (tResult.length>0)
            {related_approver=tResult[0][0]+related_approver;               
        }
}
```

Comment: `Is this the database reason or my code's error?` You've provided no knowledge about your database other than to say it's Oracle. This question is impossible to answer.

Comment: You need to provide more information; there's so many reasons why your code might be slow. How big is your database, how are the indexes set up, is your database hosted externally (if so what's the latency) etc.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off writing one query fetching n rows rather than n queries fetching one row.